# error ffmpeg Cannot open display :0.0+0,0, error 1. :0.0+0,0: Input/output error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, ffmpeg

Hello I get this error when i want to capture my screen on linux with ffmpeg ubuntu 16:04 :

the command i'am using :

```
$ ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 15 -s 1920x1080 -i :0.0+0,0 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video0
    ffmpeg version 4.1.1-0york1~16.04 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 20160609
      configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='0york1~16.04' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
      libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
      libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
      libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
      libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
      libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
      libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
      libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
      libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
      libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
    [x11grab @ 0x5611f156e540] Cannot open display :0.0+0,0, error 1.
    :0.0+0,0: Input/output error
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to grab from more than one source:

You have listed x11 (which would be your screen) as well have listed /dev/video0 (which would be a web cam or other device like a tv tuner)

Get rid of the -f v4l2 /dev/video0 at the end and add a filename with an extension like capture.mkv

If this is something you plan to do on a regular basis, I would recommend OBS

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:obsproject/obs-studio
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install obs-studio

or see link here if that doesn't work

https://www.ubuntupit.com/how-to-install-obs-screen-recorder-in-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: obs studio need graphics card i want without using gpu

Comment: obs can do either 

Just select Encoder: Software (x264 low CPU usage preset)